# using position() function in xslt

Tags: xslt

```
<EmployeeDetails>
    <Employee>
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
</EmployeeDetails>
```

I tried using xslt as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xd"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="EmployeeDetails/Employee">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For above xslt the output for position() is printing as 2,4,6,8,10.

and the output should be :

```
<EmployeeDetails>
    <Employee id="1">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="3">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="4">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="5">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
</EmployeeDetails>
```

How to print as a sequence like 1,2,3.... for id attribute.

Comment: This is because it counts text-nodes as well (whitespace).

Comment: @khachik: Yes, but not only those. `position()` function inside content template refers to **current node list**.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `xsl:number` instruction was made precisely for this task:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Employee">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:number/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<EmployeeDetails>
    <Employee id="1">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="3">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="4">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="5">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
</EmployeeDetails>
```

Comment: +1 good answer, more robust than using position(), which requires the programmer to really understand how XSLT processes the input. Unlike position(), `<xsl:number>` is designed for this purpose. `<xsl:number>` is not as widely known as `position()`, and has its own complexities because it is so powerful and flexible. But this example shows how simple it can be to use in common cases.

Comment: @Alenjandro , +1 , simple and neat answer .

Comment: @Madhu CM: I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Before your first `<xsl:template>`, add

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

This will get rid of the whitespace-only text nodes @khachik is referring to. Then your position counts should be what you expect.

Comment: Using `*` could well be correct. But if it isn't you could always use `xsl:preserve-space` to include any elements where the white space should be respected.

Comment: @Per: right. You could also do just `<xsl:strip-space elements="EmployeeDetails">`.

Comment: @LarsH: Problem is not only about white space only text nodes. `position()` function inside content template refers to **current node list**.

Comment: @Alej: how is that not only about white-space-only text nodes? In the given input XML, when the template match="EmployeeDetails/Employee" is instantiated, it is done from the built-in template operating on `<EmployeeDetails>`, which is doing `<xsl:apply-templates />`. In the absence of the select attribute in the built-in template, the context node list consists of all children of `<EmployeeDetails>`, which includes only `<Employee>` elements and text nodes. So I don't understand what you mean that it "is not only about whitespace-only text nodes".

Comment: @LarsH: The concept is that the current node list is defined by the `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` in the "any element" rule. Thus, `position()` isn't a garantee for the correct value because `node()` will selects text nodes, comments, processing instructions and elements.

Comment: @Alej - you're right about the match="*" rule, which I forgot about; but the input XML shows us that even "@*|node()" has nothing to select except <Employee> elements and whitespace-only text nodes: there are no attributes, comments, or PIs. I guess you're arguing in the abstract.

Comment: @LarsH: I agree. But question title **is** `using position() function in xslt`.

Answer (score 2):

This template generates what you need:

```
<xsl:template match="EmployeeDetails/Employee">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Employee) + 1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

[Source information](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N6099.html#d8488e314).

Comment: But this wont copy <Name> element inside each Employee.

Comment: after adding <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates> it works thaks

Comment: @Madhu it is a replacement for your template that uses `position()`.