# understanding position() function in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a similar problem as this guy:

[using position() function in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449810/using-position-function-in-xslt)

But I dont need the numbering, I just want to understand the way it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
<a>blah</a>
<a>blah</a>
<a>blah</a>
<a>blah</a>
</test>
```

for this input, the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="select">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/><br/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs:

```
<html><body>
2<br>blah
4<br>blah
6<br>blah
8<br>blah
</body></html>
```

Why does it skip the uneven numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using position() function in xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449810/using-position-function-in-xslt)

Comment: What is the purpose of `<xsl:template match="select">` in your stylesheet? Your input doesn't have an element named `select`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does it skip the uneven numbers?

Because while you were at the `/` level, you said:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

which applies templates to all nodes children of the root node, and (due to the built-in template rules) to all of their descendants  - **including the text nodes that separate the `<a>` elements**.

You will get a different result with an input of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test><a>blah</a><a>blah</a><a>blah</a><a>blah</a></test>
```

or if you add an instruction to your stylesheet to:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

or if you apply templates selectively, e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//a"/>
```

Comment: Strictly speaking the `a` elements are not children of the root node `/`, they're grandchildren.

Comment: @IanRoberts You're right. My point is that they and the text nodes separating them are siblings.

Comment: True, but when you say it's the fault of the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in the `/` template that's wrong. Even if you changed that to say `<xsl:apply-templates select="test"/>` it wouldn't change the numbers being output as they stem from the use of the default rule on the `test` element.

Comment: I suppose making it `select="test/a"` would work though.

Comment: @IanRoberts The point here is that templates are applied indiscriminately from the context of `a`'s parent.  It **is** the fault of the <xsl:apply-templates/> in the `/` template, albeit an indirect one. Anyway I have edited my answer in an effort to make this more clear. I believe that in conjunction with your answer the full picture is being presented here.

Answer (score 9):

The `position()` function gives you the position of the current node within the "current node list", which is whatever was `select`-ed by the nearest `apply-templates` or `for-each` (XSLT 2.0 refers to "items" and "sequences" rather than nodes and node lists but the principle is the same).

In your example the root template applies templates to its two child nodes (the text node containing the line break after the xml declaration, and the `test` element). There's no explicit rule matching `test` so the default rule applies, which for elements means `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.

Thus when the `a` template fires its "current node list" is the set of all 9 child nodes of `test`. This list consists of alternating text nodes (the line breaks) and element nodes (the `a` elements), with the text nodes at the odd positions and the element nodes at the even positions.

If you added an explicit template for `test` like this:

```
<xsl:template match="test">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Then this would select *only* the 4 `a` element nodes as the current node list, so `position()` would give you 1, 2, 3 and 4.